# How to add Sublime Text to contextual menu without Admin Privileges on Windows

Tags: windows, sublimetext3

I do not have administrator privileges at office and I would like to add Sublime Text to contextual menu to edit easily my files such as Notepad++. Is it possible? I've only found how to add it with Administrators privileges

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often we do not have administrator privileges at office on our PC, so some weeks ago I found a useful [guide](http://jagtechlinks.blogspot.com/2015/02/setting-context-menu-without-admin.html) to add Sublime to the contextual menu.

First you need create a new text document with any text editor, copy and paste the below script, save it on your desktop with `.bat` extension

```
@reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%1\"" /f
```

Keep in mind that you must replace `%st3Path%` with your current SublimeText directory, e.g: `C:/Tools/sublime/sublimetext.exe`

Double-click on that file to apply the settings. Now you can see Sublime in the context menu.

On the other hand we may need to remove Sublime from contextual menu, for to do that you can use the following script, and repeat the same steps above:

```
@reg delete  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /f >nul 2>&1
@reg delete  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3" /f >nul 2>&1
```

Or if you prefer, here's the script ready to use it: [SublimeText-ContextualMenu.bat](https://gist.github.com/jcalvopinam/77e6337ab8287acfc9646f20808bf527)

Comment: the script is awesome, I can choose to add it with or without admin privileges, the option to remove is fantastic, it really is easy to use, very useful! thank you so much!